# foreach within mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am new to php and trying to create one query dynamically. This is the piece of code which I get foreach syntax error. Can please you help me to fix the bug?

```
    $select = "SELECT pmid FROM articles WHERE pmid IN 
("
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $select .= $result['pmid'] . ',';
    }
    $select = trim($select,','); . 
")
           ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of line 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pmids = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $pmids[] = $result['pmid'];
}

if (!empty($pmids)) {
  $select = 'SELECT pmid FROM articles WHERE pmid IN (' . join(',',$pmids) . ')';
} else {
  $select = 'SELECT pmid FROM articles WHERE 1 = 0';
}
```

You have to make sure that the `$result['pmid']` values are safe to be used literally in database queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct way of writting sql query ..

Write it properly

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $select .= $result['pmid'] . ',';
}
$select = trim($select,',');

$query = "SELECT pmid FROM articles WHERE pmid IN ($select)";
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this

```
$results = array(1,5,6,7);
$select = "SELECT pmid FROM articles WHERE pmid IN (".implode(",", $results).")";
echo $select;
```